# Sanity CLI Importing Old Data Despite New Dataset Export

Tags: database, import, sanity

I'm currently working with Sanity and I'm trying to export data from one dataset and import it into another. Specifically, I'm exporting documents of type 'adventure' from my 'production' dataset and then importing them into my 'startfrenchnow' dataset.

I'm using the following commands:

```
sanity dataset export production ./production-adventure.tar.gz --types adventure
sanity dataset import ./production-adventure.tar.gz startfrenchnow --replace
```

However, I'm encountering an issue where the import command seems to be importing old data (documents of type 'success') that I had previously imported and then deleted from the 'startfrenchnow' dataset. The .tar.gz file I'm trying to import only contains 'adventure' documents, so I'm not sure why the 'success' documents are being imported again.

I suspect this might be a caching issue, where the Sanity CLI is somehow using a cached version of the old import file. I've tried changing the name of the import file and verifying its contents, but the issue persists.

Has anyone encountered this issue before or have any suggestions on how to resolve it?

Thank you in advance for your help.